# Parallax effect in iOS sidebar menus

Tags: ios, swift, parallax, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

Up until now, I was using the `SWRevealViewController` library, available at GitHub. This worked well for me, as you can see here:

[image]

**How can I achieve parallax effect in this sidebar menu?**

Furthermore, I also tried some other ways more specific to my target, like 
https://github.com/SSA111/SSASideMenu.

And I got this result:

[image]

But just after any type of GRE Test is selected, the front view with that specific category selected is shown.

[image]

But now on clicking menu bar button at the top of GRE Main, the sidebar menu does not appear, and instead gives this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This error is targeted in library file `SSASideMenu`, where it says that parent ViewController is found nil for this front view controller. Because `SSASideMenu` check the sender by its parent.

If parent matches `SSASideView`, then it loads sidebar menu.

Here is my code:

```
extension UIViewController {

    var sideMenuViewController: SSASideMenu? {
        get {
            print(" >>>>>>>>>> ????????? ///////////// Here we are")
            return getSideViewController(self)
        }
    }

    private func getSideViewController(viewController: UIViewController) -> SSASideMenu? {

        var parent = viewController.parentViewController

        if parent == viewController.parentViewController {
            if parent is SSASideMenu
            {
                print("2nd Step")
                return parent as? SSASideMenu
            }
            else
            {
                parent = viewController.parentViewController
                print("1st Step")
                return getSideViewController(parent!)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    @IBAction func presentLeftMenuViewController() {
        sideMenuViewController?._presentLeftMenuViewController()
    }

    func showPresent()
    {
        print("Hello")
        sideMenuViewController?._presentLeftMenuViewController()
    }

    @IBAction func presentRightMenuViewController() {
        sideMenuViewController?._presentRightMenuViewController()
    }

}
```

Finally, in the ViewController it is simply used as

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SSASideMenu.showPresent), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Create a new issue in github's project?

Comment: @Brian ... Answer it also lol .... editing is not fairly technical